# Yesterday date using VBS code and batch file (format : YYYY_MM_DD)

Tags: date, batch-file, vbscript

Using batch I want to create a variable that contains yesterday date, precisely I need this format : "YYYY_MM_DD"

I succeed to have this format : YYYYMMDD

I created a vbs file "yesterday.vbs" :

```
d = date() - 1
wscript.echo year(d) * 10000 + month(d) * 100 + day(d)
```

And in my batch file I called my code :

```
REM ----------------   Yesterday VAR  ---------------------

for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo yesterday.vbs') do set yesterday=%%a
```

I want to have this format :

YYYY_MM_DD

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To split down your task into two separate files, as you have done:

[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F %%A In ('CScript //NoLogo "yesterday.vbs"') Do Set "Yesterday=%%A"
Echo(%Yesterday%
Pause
```

[vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript):

```bat
dtmYesterday = DateAdd("d", -1, Now())
strDate = Year(dtmYesterday) & "_" & Right("0" & Month(dtmYesterday), 2) _
  & "_" & Right("0" & Day(dtmYesterday), 2)
WScript.Echo strDate
```

If you wanted to create the [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript) from your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), run it, then delete it:

```bat
@Echo Off
(   Echo dtmYesterday = DateAdd("d", -1, Now(^)^)
    Echo strDate = Year(dtmYesterday^) ^& "_" ^& Right("0" ^& Month(dtmYesterday^), 2^) ^& "_" ^& Right("0" ^& Day(dtmYesterday^), 2^)
    Echo WScript.Echo strDate)>"yesterday.vbs"
For /F %%A In ('CScript //NoLogo yesterday.vbs') Do Set "Yesterday=%%A"
Del "yesterday.vbs"
Echo(%Yesterday%
Pause
```

Alternatively, you could still use [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript), but embed it directly into your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
<!-- :
@Echo Off
For /F %%A In ('CScript //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf"') Do Set "Yesterday=%%A"
Echo(%Yesterday%
Pause
GoTo :EOF
-->
<Job><Script Language="VBScript">
    dtmYesterday = DateAdd("d", -1, Now())
    strDate = Year(dtmYesterday) & "_" & Right("0" & Month(dtmYesterday), 2) _
      & "_" & Right("0" & Day(dtmYesterday), 2)
    WScript.Echo strDate
  </Script></Job>
```

---

All that being said, I would suggest you forget about [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript), and use [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) from your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) instead:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F %%A In ('PowerShell -NoP "(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyy_MM_dd')"'
)Do Set "Yesterday=%%A"
Echo(%Yesterday%
Pause
```

Comment: Nicely written. The problem with PowerShell is it is so damn slow to launch (at least the first time). For this reason I always prefer JScript or VBS over PowerShell, provided they can handle the task.